# "Illegal output or inout port connection for "port"

Tags: verilog

I have coded a small code for two point FFT, where my inputs ( 64-bit complex) are in IEEE-754 format(double precision). Here is the link for my codes (butterfly module, adder/subtractor module, testbench):

http://pastebin.com/RNRx6J2E

when I try simulating the testbench I am facing the following list of errors:

http://pastebin.com/LRnRzv4A

P.S : I am beginner, so, my style of writing may be bad. Please help me solving this issue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Y55fKX81 @toolic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to [this](http://pastebin.com/Y55fKX81) link provided in comment by OP. Your code works fine with all SystemVerilog simulators. The **output** of module **must be connected** to a `wire`. Refer the following figure:

[image: Port connection rules]

The **output port** from **inside** the module can be a `reg` or `wire`. But, when that module is **instantiated**, it **must** be connected to a **net** or `wire`.

Referring to [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), Section 23.3.3:

> Each port connection shall be a **continuous assignment** of **source to**
>   **sink**, where one connected item shall be a signal source and the other
>   shall be a signal sink. The assignment shall be a continuous
>   assignment from source to sink for input or output ports.

When the ports  are **connected** in an instantiation, to any other port, it is a **constant assignment**, and hence it always requires the **target port to be a net**.

So, in this code, connect **wires** to the output module `add_sub` and assign the values of wires to the `reg` `outr1`,`outr2` etc.

```
  // Draw wires to be connected as output
  wire [63:0] t1,t2,ti1,ti2;

  // Drive all regs from values of wires
  always @*
    begin
      outr1 = t1;
      outr2 = t2;
      outi1 = ti1;
      outi2 = ti2;
    end

  // Change : Wires connection
  add_sub adder1(en,clk,inr1[63],inr2[63],inr1[62:52],inr2[62:52],inr1[51:0],inr2[51:0],1'b0,t1[63],t1[62:52],t1[51:0]);
  //...
```

I have simulated your code with all simulators at [EDAPlayground here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/ZsW) and it works fine. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090239/verilog-error-must-be-connected-to-a-structural-net-expression) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219047/port-connection-rules-in-verilog) similar questions.

Comment: [Additional info] I was trying to assign a signal of type `reg` to another one of type `wire` when this error appeared. (e.g., `<wire_type_signal> <= <reg_type_signal>`). The error vanished when I deleted that line.